# Definition of modulus of velocity in computational fluid dynamics

Tags: computational-physics

I am studying[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KTId.png), and I came by a definition that I am not familiar.

[image: From 1]

What is the mathematical and physical definition of modulus of velocity according to the image?

References:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KTId.png) Hirsch, Charles. (2007). Numerical Computation of Internal and External Flows: The Fundamentals of Computational Fluid Dynamics. Elsevier

Answer (score 1):

Modulus is just the length of the velocity vector, in other words:

$$|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$$

Or in physics terminology, velocity magnitude.

Try to see if you understand the simplification in case $\vec{v}=(v,0,0)$.

Comment: OK, that is what I thought it might be. Thank you.